# How to get shown.bs.modal to trigger when the modal uses a remote URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

## The Problem

I cannot get `shown.bs.modal` to fire correctly when my modal is generated by passing in a remote url.

In the following code the `hidden.bs.modal` consistently work.

## The Code

```
$('#my_modal').on("shown.bs.modal", set_up_modal);
$('#my_modal').on("hidden.bs.modal", tear_down_modal);
$('#my_modal').modal({ remote: target_url  });

set_up_modal    = function() { console.log('up') };
tear_down_modal = function() { console.log('down') };
```

## What I have tried

I have [read the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage).

I have tried changing my `.on` to read more like `$('body').on("shown.bs.modal", '#my_modal', saa.set_up_modal);` but this has produced no change (again `hidden.bs.modal` works).

## Update

I have added `console.log($._data( $('#my_modal')[0], "events" ));` and can confirm that `shown` is being bound to the object, just not getting called.

I have tried using `show.bs.modal` instead, this works but I need the elements to be visible on screen for what I want to do to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a temporary solution from a pull request here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/4b1a6e11326fee97a5ebc194be040086f40f97fb

Editing line 81 of the modal.js file as per below has fixed the issue for me until the pull request is made

```
-        that.$element.find('.modal-dialog') // wait for modal to slide in
+        that.$element // wait for modal to slide in
```